# profiles in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, profiles

I am trying to understand how to use @profiles in spring-batch.
I created a java file with two classes in it:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("nonlocal")
class NonLocalConfiguration {
}
and
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
class LocalConfiguration {
}
```

in the main java class I am trying to set the profiles as follows:

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationcontext.xml");
String run_env = System.getenv("profile");
System.out.println("run_env is: " + run_env);
context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(run_env);
context.refresh();
```

I set the profile using an Environment variable as profile=local

When the program is executed, I get a null pointer exception which I think is not getting the profile correctly. How can I use profiles concept in Spring Batch? Will it be different in normal spring vs spring batch?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood, you have to set the profile **before** you create the ApplicationContext. Once the application contenxt is created, changing the profile will not have any influence.

From the SpringBoot documentation, chapter 25.2 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

> Programmatically setting profiles 
>   You can programmatically set active
>   profiles by calling SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles(…​) **before**
>   your application runs. It is also possible to activate profiles using
>   Spring’s ConfigurableEnvironment interface.